# unity join 2 rooms together at door positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game idea of making a procedurally generated side scroller. This would be made up of 3d game objects that represent various platform sections. Where I need help, is on joining them together at doorway entrances and exits on the sections, similar to the Dungen asset available on the store. I have this asset and have tried to make it work for this. But it is more suited for 2d or 3d specific games. To be honest, I have no idea where to even begin coding this. If I try to use the game asset transform positions. I can get close. But still not make it work. Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to code this!

```
   float sxl = startRoom.transform.GetChild(0).transform.localPosition.x;
    float syl = startRoom.transform.GetChild(0).transform.localPosition.y;
    float szl = startRoom.transform.GetChild(0).transform.localPosition.z;
    float exl = roomList.room[selectedRoom].transform.GetChild(0).transform.localPosition.x;
    float eyl = roomList.room[selectedRoom].transform.GetChild(0).transform.localPosition.y;
    float ezl = roomList.room[selectedRoom].transform.GetChild(0).transform.localPosition.z;
    float txl = sxl + exl;
    float tyl = syl + eyl;
    float tzl = szl + ezl;

    float sx = startRoom.transform.GetChild(0).transform.position.x;
    float sy = startRoom.transform.GetChild(0).transform.position.y;
    float sz = startRoom.transform.GetChild(0).transform.position.z;
    float ex = roomList.room[selectedRoom].transform.GetChild(0).transform.position.x;
    float ey = roomList.room[selectedRoom].transform.GetChild(0).transform.position.y;
    float ez = roomList.room[selectedRoom].transform.GetChild(0).transform.position.z;
    float tx = sx + ex;
    float ty = sy + ey;
    float tz = sz + ez;
    Debug.Log("###:(" + sxl + "," + syl + "," + szl + "),(" + exl + "," + eyl + "," + ezl + "),(" + txl + "," + tyl + "," + tzl + ")" +
            ",(" + sx + "," + sy + "," + sz + "),(" + ex + "," + ey + "," + ez + "),(" + tx + "," + ty + "," + tz + ")");

    Instantiate(roomList.room[selectedRoom], new Vector3(
        startRoom.transform.GetChild(0).transform.localPosition.x +
        roomList.room[selectedRoom].transform.GetChild(0).transform.localPosition.x,
        startRoom.transform.GetChild(0).transform.localPosition.y +
        roomList.room[selectedRoom].transform.GetChild(0).transform.localPosition.y,
        startRoom.transform.GetChild(0).transform.localPosition.z +
        roomList.room[selectedRoom].transform.GetChild(0).transform.localPosition.z
        ), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I have it working enough to start making the rest of the game. As usual, I was over thinking it!!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BuildRooms : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] GameObject startRoom;
[SerializeField] RoomList roomList;
[SerializeField] int numberOfRooms = 5;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    GameObject currentRoom = startRoom;
    GameObject newRoom;
    //roomList = new RoomList();
    Debug.Log("currentRoom:" + currentRoom.name);

    if (startRoom == null) Debug.LogError("Start Room is not given!");
    if (roomList == null) Debug.LogError("Room list is not given!");


        if (roomList.room.Length == 0) Debug.LogError("RoomList.rooms is empty!");

        int numOfRooms = roomList.room.Length;


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRooms; i++)
        {

        int selectedRoom = Random.Range(0, numOfRooms);

        //get horizontal position of doorway in the object to be added
        float offset = roomList.room[selectedRoom].transform.GetChild(1).transform.localPosition.z;
        //if new doorway is in a negative position, it needs to be made in to a positive, before adding it to are current position!
        if (offset < 0) offset = offset * -1;

        float newZPosition = currentRoom.transform.GetChild(1).transform.position.z + offset;

        newRoom = Instantiate(roomList.room[selectedRoom], new Vector3(
            roomList.room[selectedRoom].transform.GetChild(1).transform.localPosition.x,
            roomList.room[selectedRoom].transform.GetChild(1).transform.localPosition.y - 0.03f,
            newZPosition
            ), Quaternion.identity);

        newRoom.transform.parent = this.transform;
        currentRoom = newRoom;
        Debug.Log("currentRoom:" + currentRoom.name + ":" + newZPosition );
        }
    }

}
```